# Removing object properties using jQuery map() and dynamic property names?

Tags: jquery, object

I'm trying to remove properties from an object if its name has a length greater than 1, using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var result = { a :{}, b : {}, invalid : {} };

result = $.map(result, function(val, prop){
   return prop.length > 1 ? null : { prop : val };
});

console.log(result);
```

Console shows that `result` is **now an array** (not an object as it should be) and **`prop` is taken literally** (i.e. there are many properties named "prop" inside the array).

Any help would be great!

**EDIT**: solution combining `.map()` and `delete`:

```
$.map(result, function(val, prop){
   if(prop.length > 1) delete result[prop]; // val is unused but required
});
```

Comment: `$.map` will *always* return an array.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker thank you, that's not a problem, i can deal with an array the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `$.map` is ill-suited for this task. I would fall back on a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) properties you don't want:

```
var result = { a :{}, b : {}, invalid : {} };

for (var prop in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if (prop.length > 1) {
            delete result[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LHFdp/

If you really want to use `$.map`, you can access properties dynamically using `[]` (See [this useful article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on MDN for more information about working with objects):

```
var result = { a :{}, b : {}, invalid : {} };

result = $.map(result, function (val, prop) {
    var obj = {};
    if (prop.length > 1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        obj[prop] = val;
        return obj;
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qrwjU/

Comment: Thanks. I'll look for combine `$.map` and `delete` for better readability.

Comment: @Gremo: At that point you could just use `$.each` instead of `$.map`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `map` gives you an array from the array or object you pass to it. It returns all the items from the array or object matching the condition in the callback. You can control what you want in the resulting array.